# Thunderbird always places device on iMac desktop when started

Tags: macos, thunderbird

Installed Thunderbird on new iMac and each time the app is started it places a device on the desktop and a window with the Thunderbird icon and an arrow pointing to the app folder.

Is there a way to open the app by clicking on the icon on the dock without the Thunderbird putting this clutter on the desktop?

Answer (score 0):

You're not running an app, you're opening a Disk Image.  Apps are commonly distributed on a .dmg file. That's a disk image -- a file that acts like a disk when opened (i.e. acts like you inserted a CD or thumb drive).  Finder mounts it just like a physical drive.

Open the disk image, then drag the app from the image to the Applications folder. (That's why there's a shortcut to Applications there, to make it easy for you!)

After you've copied the app to Applications, close the disk image ("eject" the "drive"), and then trash the .dmg file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where might I find the .dmg file to trash it?

Comment: Probably in the Downloads folder in you user Home folder